# How to replace "ta" in a string "potato" in c++? 2 characters for 1

Tags: c++, string

Here is the code:

```
string msg;
        niceArray = txtReader("chatTest/replaces.txt");
        vector<vector<string>>vMaster;
        if(vMaster.size() <1){
            string arr[] = { "a","A","Ã¡","@","Ã ","Ã¢","Ã£","ÃÃ","€Ã","ƒÃ"}; 
            vector<string> tempA(arr, arr+4);
            vMaster.push_back(tempA);//"aAÃ¡@Ã Ã¢Ã£ÃÃ€ÃƒÃ‚"
        }

        string ex;

        while(sstr.good()){
            sstr>>ex;
            vectorCheck.push_back(ex);
        }

        for(int e = 0; e < vectorCheck.size(); e=e+1){
            //if(e > vectorCheck[e].length()) break;
            auto str = vectorCheck[e];
            for(int b = 0; b < vMaster.size(); b=b+1){
                for(int j=0; vMaster[b].size(); j=j+1){
                    //int f = str.find(vMaster[b][j]);
                    if(str.find(vMaster[b][j]) != std::string::npos){
                            int f = str.find(vMaster[b][j]);
                        //if(vMaster[b][j].length() > 1){
                            str.replace(f,2,vMaster[b][0]);
                            //break;
                    //  }
                        //
                    }
                }
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < xingArray.size(); i=i+1){
                if(str == xingArray[i]){
                    vectorCheck[e] = niceArray[rand() % niceArray.size()];
                }
            }

        }
```

So for each sentence i type i am checking each word and looking if there is any of that string arr characteres in it, if there is i replace it for the vector[0] in this case "a".

The problem is that this line `str.find(vMaster[b][j]) != std::string::npos` never returns me -1... Even when i type like "c" in finds c in there or "f" or any word and i get an error. The funny stuff is that when i type like "á" that turns into "Ã|" it works and with the "ã" that turns into "Ã£" it doesnt give me 0 again... I really dont know whats going on... I really tried hard here and if anyone has any opinion i would like to hear thanks.

Comment: At first show some code ta (:D) display a minimal effort.

Comment: you should use `boost` and `std` for that task.
Also, you can manipulate with `OpenCL/OpenMP/OpenGL` for better productivity on CPUs/GPUs

Comment: It sounds like you have character encoding problems. I think the things starting with the funny A are UTF-8 encoded characters.

Comment: Yeah i know its encoding i just dont know what to do, all i wanted was a way to convert this funny Ã¢ into the normal à but i can

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string str ("potato.");
std::string str2 ("ta");

std::size_t found = str.find(str2);
if ( found != std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "first 'ta' found at: " << found << '\n';

str.replace( found, 2, "");
```

Comment: I tried to find "Ã£" in "viÃ£do" but it doesnt return me more than -1 if i put just "Ã£" to find "Ã£" it gives me 0 and works... what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Updated my question please give a look

Answer (score 0):

I dont think C++ has any single method to find and replace so why not use inbuilt find and then replace.
For example:

```
void find_and_replace(string& source, string const& find, string const& replace)
{
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; (i = source.find(find, i)) != std::string::npos;)
    {
        source.replace(i, find.length(), replace);
        i += replace.length() - find.length() + 1;
    }
}
int main()
{
    string text = "potato";
    find_and_replace(text, "ta", "");
    cout << "After one replacement: " << text << endl;
    find_and_replace(text, "te", "");
    cout << "After another replacement: " << text << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Updated my question please give a look